# How to reset the date field when form is cleared

Tags: angular, datepicker

I have a form with a date field.  Initially, the date field is empty. When the user selects a date and then clicks the clear button, the input data stays there.

I tried date=null and undefined but didnt work

ts

```
private clearValues(row: RecordDto) {
  row.Date= null
  row.contactName = null
}
```

html

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="Date" >
    <div class="date-picker-container" >
      <input class="date-picker form-control" ngx-mydatepicker
             (dateChanged)="onDueDateUpdate($event, row)"
             [options]="datePickerOptions" #dueDatePicker="ngx-mydatepicker"
             [errorStateMatcher]="matcher"
             [appRequiredIf]="selection.isSelected(row)"/>
      <button type="button" mat-button class="button-calendar"
              (click)="dueDatePicker.toggleCalendar()"
              [disabled]="row.taskName.notApplicable"></button>
    </div>
  </mat-form-field>
</td>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: do you want to reset to current date ?

Comment: no. clear the field

Answer (score 1):

The `ngx-mydatepicker` library has an inbuilt function to clear the date (See documentation: https://github.com/kekeh/ngx-mydatepicker/blob/master/README.md#cleardate-function). `#dueDatePicker="ngx-mydatepicker"` defines the local variable name `dueDatePicker`. You can use this variable to call the inbuilt functions of `ngx-mydatepicker` (See documentation: https://github.com/kekeh/ngx-mydatepicker/blob/master/README.md#functions)

Then in your component, access `dueDatePicker` using `@ViewChild` and clear the date.

```
import { NgxMyDatePickerDirective } from 'ngx-mydatepicker';

...

@ViewChild('dueDatePicker') dueDate: NgxMyDatePickerDirective;

private clearValues(row: RecordDto) {
  this.dueDate.clearDate();
  row.contactName = null;
}
```

Comment: should I create a class for NgxMyDatePickerDirective @nash11

Comment: @queue no, just import ````NgxMyDatePickerDirective```` from ````ngx-mydatepicker````. I have edited my answer to show the same.

Comment: there are many rows in a table. but it clears date only once for the date in the first row. It doesnt work for other row dates

Comment: @queue I was not aware you had multiple rows. You should be able to use ````ViewChildren```` to solve this. It would be really helpful if you could provide more code or even better create a reproducible app on stackblitz.

Comment: ViewChildren didnt work. It is a lot of code and I know hot how to make the specific part work on stackblitz